# Is there a paper design software for ubuntu?

Tags: music, scribus

Or what would you use for a such task ? Scribus ?

I wish to experiment with a new kind of music notation wich I'm developing and I need to have a customized sheet paper.

Answer (score 0):

Scribus is very good, but, if you have time to spend, you could learn LaTeX (which is a markup language to be used with a text editor, not a program) which gives you much more control on what you are doing.